# Unexpected error while getting the method or property deleteText on object DocumentApp.Text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm getting an error when trying to use `DocumentApp.openById(123).getBody().editAsText().deleteText(start, end)`:

> "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property deleteText on object DocumentApp.Text".

I've tried manually adding the `oauthScopes` to the manifest file, but this did not solve the problem.

Here's an example of my usage of the `deleteText()` method:

```
let body = DocumentApp.openById(123);
let text = body.editAsText();

if (testValue == comparisonValue) {
  // removes the unwanted text from the start of the matched text. 
  Logger.log(`[LOGIC] comparison was true, so deleting ${match.index} to ${match.index + ifClause.length - 1}`);
  text.deleteText(match.index, match.index + unwantedText.length - 1);
  continue;
}
```

Comment: make sure your arguments are correct type

Comment: Both arguments are integers, and I also tried using `parseInt()` on both arguments to ensure they're definitely integers. Still no luck.

Comment: I think first you have to find the range element and then you can apply the indexes within the range element.

Comment: I used indexOf() and it returns a number, what happens if you Logger.log(typeof match). Maybe you're taking a different thing from your bodytext.

Comment: This question is discussed in [official chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53698668#53698668)

Comment: The problem seems irreproducible. No feedback for several days. Vote to close

Comment: Agreed. I can't contribute to this any more and haven't been able to uncover anything more. I ended up going with a different implementation as I couldn't figure out what was going wrong here.

Comment: @Lewis so... Out of curiosity, did you try checking the suggestions I [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53699477#53699477)?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the error:

```
var id = '###';
var testValue = 0;
var comparisonValue = 0;
var match = {index: 0};
var unwantedText = 'abc';
var ifClause = '123';

function myFunction() {

  let body = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  let text = body.editAsText();

  if (testValue == comparisonValue) {
    // removes the unwanted text from the start of the matched text. 
    Logger.log(`[LOGIC] comparison was true, so deleting ${match.index} to ${match.index + ifClause.length - 1}`);
    text.deleteText(match.index, match.index + unwantedText.length - 1);
    // continue;
  }
}
```

[image]

Everything works fine. It successfully removes first three characters from the text.

Can the `continue;` statement be the problem?